# Why can't I fill sumcount in Counting Sort using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, sorting, list-comprehension, counting-sort

```
def countsort(alist):
    maxi=alist[0]

    for i in alist:
        if i>maxi:
            maxi=i

    indexlist=[i for i in range(0,maxi+1)]
    count=[alist.count(i) for i in indexlist]
    sumcount=[0 for i in range(0,maxi+1)]
    print(indexlist)
    print(count)

    sumcount=[count[i] if i==0 else count[i] + sumcount[i - 1]  for i in range(0, len(sumcount))]
    print(sumcount)

    sorted_input=[0 for i in range(0,len(alist)+1)]
    for i in alist:
        sorted_input[sumcount[i]]=i
        sumcount[i]-=1

    return sorted_input[1:]

#count output = [0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,1,1,1]
#expected sumcount output = [0,0,1,1,3,3,3,3,4,5,6]
#sumcount output using list comprehension = count      

alist=[9,4,10,8,2,4]
s_l=countsort(alist)
print(s_l)
```

Problem is if I try to modify sumcount using a list comprehension, index values do not change. Why is that? Why can't I simultaneously modify and access values through list comprehension?

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to be doing? Perhaps by showing an example input and expected output?

Comment: It is a sorting method. Okay I will update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be bothered to grok your whole code, but here's a difference between the commented-out code and the list comprehension:

When you are accessing `sumcount[i - 1]` in the `if`/`else` construct, `sumcount` might already have been updated at index `i - 1`.

With the list comprehension, you always index into the unmodified `sumcount` without mutating it while building the list.

Comment: Hello, that's my problem. With the list comprehension, sumcount does not hold any of the 'supposed to have been inserted values'. With proper looping, values are being inserted properly. So I guess my question is why can't I simultaneously modify and access the modified sumcount with list comprehension?

Comment: @OrestesPapanastassiou because you are building a new list from scratch with the list comprehension and then reassign the name `sumcount` to that new list. You don't modify the old `sumcount` while the list comprehension executes.